# Spreadsheet App converting Date()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Problem: Spreadsheet isn't recognizing an input date as a Date(), so I can't get the .getTime() from it in Apps Script.

Question: Can you see why this is?

Results:
Here is a part of the script I'm running:

```
dates.map(function(inp) {
  if (inp != undefined && inp !== ""){
    inp = new Date(inp.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000);
    return inp
  }
});
```

where `dates` refers to a range: `dates = sheet.getRange(2,1, lastR, 1).getValues();`

Currently this range has a manually inputed value of "2017-05-20" which Spreadsheet automagtically recognizes as the date "Sat May 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"

The error reads as follows:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object Sat May 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST). (line 86, file "Code") Details Dismiss

I have tried a million ways throughout my script to get Spreadsheet to stop autoconverting the input values as dates, so that I can make then at least timestamps or something. Does any one know why it is doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you call `getValues()` on a one-column range it will still be an array of arrays.

What's confusing here is that GAS tries to be helpful and displays the only value in the one-element array.

Extracting the first element from the row should fix this issue.

```
dates.map(function(row) {
  var inp = row[0];
  if (inp != undefined && inp !== ""){
    inp = new Date(inp.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000);
    return inp
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works towards the goal, but the problem is still that the final "dates" doesn't show the updated value...:

[17-05-22 19:06:50:561 CEST] Sat May 20 02:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017
[17-05-22 19:06:50:561 CEST] -7200000.0
[17-05-22 19:06:50:562 CEST] [[Sat May 20 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2017], []]

the first log being the "inp", the second the TimezoneOffset, and the third the final "dates". Do you know whats happening?

Comment: Not sure I understand the log without the calls. Can you provide a reproducible example please? Where is date defined? Are you  aware getTimezoneOffset returns minutes, not hours?

Comment: `var dates = sheet.getRange(2,1, lastR, 1).getValues();  
  dates.forEach(function(row, k) {  
    var inp = row[k] 
    if (inp != undefined && inp !== ""){ 
      inp = new Date(inp.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000));
      Logger.log(inp); 
      return inp  
    }
  }); 
  
  Logger.log(date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000); 
  Logger.log(dates);`

Comment: Where is `date` defined though (not `dates`)?

Comment: date is globally defined as `var date = new Date();`

Comment: I had a look and I cannot replicate this, if you log the date before and after updating you can see that it changes, Maybe it's best if you open a new question where you can explain your problem in more detail than in a comment.

Comment: No its ok, I ended up taking what you said and changing it a bit, which works now. So thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing everything via Array.prototype.map(), the following code might work. I ignored your date manipulation logic, adding 5 days to the date in the cell instead. For the values to update, you must assign whatever Array.prototype.map() returns to a variable. Also, 2 separate checks for empty string and 'undefined' are redundant as JavaScript actually considers them both to be 'false' (Unfortunately, this applies to 0 as well, so be careful)

```
       function getDates() {

          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
          var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);
          var values = range.getValues();

          var newValues = values.map(function(row) {

          var newRow = row.map(function(value){

          if (value){

          value = new Date(value.getTime() + 3600000*24*5) // adding 5 days

          return value;

        }

   });

   return newRow;

  });

   range.setValues(newValues);


}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this did not solve the problem I had. Thanks for trying though

Comment: Everything seems to be working on my side. Maybe you could try breaking down the problem into smaller questions and ask them separately,

Comment: "Spreadsheet isn't recognizing an input date as a Date(), so I can't get the .getTime() from it in Apps Script." - This is the only problem I had, and it was solved! It existed only because I forgot to define the column in which the data was being pulled :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking Robin's recommendation, and did the following, which worked:

```
 rows.map(function(r) {
        r.day = new Date(r.day.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000));
        r.day = r.day.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        return r
      })
```

where date was globally defined as `date = new Date()`, "rows" the rows which have data in them, and "day" is the column name (of the first row [0] I had defined earlier in the script) for the column of dates I was trying to change.

Thanks again!